# UITapGestureRecognizer is not invoked when I clicked button with IBAction

Tags: ios, swift

I have UITextField and UIButton in my application.

To hide system keyboard which is shown when UITextField is clicked, I added UITapGestureRecognizer to my view.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(didTap(_:)))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

@objc func didTap(_ recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}

@IBAction func onClickedButton(_ sender: Any) {
    print("aaa")
}
```

This code worked very well when I touched outside of my button.

However, when I clicked the button which has IBAction(onClickedButton), the keyboard did not disappear and only the message "aaa" printed in output console.

What I want to do is to hide keyboard and invoke IBAction at the same time. In other words, I want to invoke Tap gesture and IBAction at the same time, when I clicked my button.

How can I acheive this?

Comment: Don't use `UITapGestureRecognizer` and a button at the same time. Instead, try `addTarget` for the "Touch Down" event.

Comment: I would recommend setting the delegate of your textfield as the parent class (probably your view or view controller) and then overriding the textfieldDidEndEditing() function from that delegate protocol.

Comment: @jcodes Could you tell me more detail? What I want to do is that invoking IBAction (ex. print "aaa") and tap gesture(hiding keyboard) at the same time when I clicked UIButton. But if I override the textfieldDidendEditing() function and print "aaa" in that function, "aaa" will be printed whenever keyboard has disappeared. How can I know whether UIButton is clicked or not in this case?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution.

Just setting

```
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

can acheive this.

By doing like this, tapGesture hides keyboard and after that, passes touch event to the UIButton.

Comment: This is the most right anwser. But would you please tell me how this works? I just cann't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `view.endEditing(true)` to your `onClickedButton`.

Comment: Is it the only way to do this? I want all my buttons to do their own IBActions and hide keyboard at the same time. So I expected more fundamental solution would exist.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(didTap(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    @objc func didTap(_ recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

    @IBAction func onClickedButton(_ sender: Any) {
        print("aaa")
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```